# Taking in Coordinates, but the wrong value is being inserted into the vector?

Tags: vector

I am parsing the user's coordinates, and I would like to add them to a vector (not sure how many will be taken in). However, the wrong value is inserted. As shown:

```
string userInput;
getline(cin,userInput);

for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
{
    if(isdigit(userInput[i]))
    {
        results.push_back(userInput[i]);
        if(isdigit(userInput[i + 1])) //check the value next to it too (max of double digits)
        {
            results[i] = 10 * (userInput[i + 1]); //add it to the vale
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter (1,2) - (3,4), the '(' is skipped, but for some reason, when it see's that 1 is a digit, it puts 49 into the vector as well as other random numbers. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userInput[i]` is `char` type. It's not random, but encoded in ASCII. '0'...'9' in ASCII is encoded in decimal 48-57. So you can use `userInput[i] - 48` or `userInput[i] - '0'` to get your int.

Another problem in your code: in each iteration, you check the value next to it, but does not skip it in next iteration, which means that if the input is `1234`, you will get a vector `{12,23,34}`

Yet another problem: your code will never catch 3-digit numbers.

Finally (hopefully), your `results[i] = 10 * (userInput[i + 1])` drops your first digit.

BTW, why not using `stringstream` to parse your input? The following function will parse one coordinate.

```
#include <sstream>

std::pair<int,int> parse_coordinate (const string& input_string) {
  std::pair<int,int> ret;
  std::stringstream in(input_string);
  if ( (in.get() == '(') && (in >> ret.first)
    && (in.get() == ',') && (in >> ret.second)
    && (in.get() == ')') ) {
    return ret;
  }
  // deal with error
  return std::make_pair(0,0);
}
```